# Visualization of TriangleMeshModel in Open3D

Tags: python, 3d, open3d, 3d-model

I have been trying to visualize 3D models in Open3D-Python by using the following code:

```
import open3d as o3d
model = o3d.io.read_triangle_model("nk1.glb") 
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([model])
```

The problem is that :-
`o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([model])` works for **Triangle mesh**, but not for **TriangleMeshModel**. It returns the error:

> draw_geometries(): incompatible function arguments. Invoked with: <open3d.cpu.pybind.visualization.rendering.TriangleMeshModel object

`o3d.visualization.draw([model])` isn't working too

I'm speculating the solution lies in using the **open3d.visualization.rendering** class to render the model (I may be wrong. Would be glad to hear other solutions too). But I'm unsure of the correct way to do it as I couldn't figure it out from the official documentation.
*Would appreciate the help!!*

Here is the link to the [documentation](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.io.read_triangle_model.html?highlight=open3d%20visualization%20rendering%20trianglemeshmodel) and some [3D Models](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14UbnE81p8siZi_7RjvwzNy0cgr1HJN1f?usp=sharing)